# Groovy Spock unit tests with closures

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, spock

How can I do this in Spock/groovy?

```
package org.jenkinsci.plugins

import hudson.matrix.*
import spock.lang.*
import org.junit.Rule
import org.jvnet.hudson.test.JenkinsRule

class xxxx extends Specification {

    @Rule JenkinsRule rule = new JenkinsRule()

    def 'matrix'() {
        given:
        def matrixProject = rule.createMatrixProject()
        AxisList axl = new AxisList();
        def axis = new TextAxis('TEST', "1", "2", "3")

        axl.add(axis)
        matrixProject.setAxes(axl)

        expect: matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().logFile.text.contains("Some String!")

        matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().getRuns().each(){
            expect: it.logFile.text.contains("Another String")
        }
    }
}
```

specifically, how can I run a closure with a nested test? The "Another String" test doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question well. However if by *nested test* you mean evaluating statement inside of *each* closure, why not just use assert

```
expect:
matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().logFile.text.contains("Some String!")
matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().getRuns().each() {
    assert it.logFile.text.contains("Another String")
}
```

@tim_yates's approach also seems fine and it's more like Spock's way. I haven't tested it though.

**EDIT**

If you want be sure that all logFiles contain test string then use 'every' method as Peter suggested.

```
expect:
...
matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().getRuns().every {
    it.text.contains('Another String')
}
```

Other approach, if you prefer to know how many logFiles don't contain test string on test fail count them and compare result size to zero:

```
expect:
...
matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().getRuns().count {
    !it.text.contains('Another String')
} == 0
```

Yet another, if you like to know which files caused test to fail, get names of those which don't contain test string and compare that to an empty list:

```
expect:
...
matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get().getRuns().findAll {
    !it.text.contains('Another String')
}*.name == []
```

Comment: This is the one but it only runs until the test fails so `assert it.logFile.text.contains("TEST/1")` fails on the second run and the third doesn't get called at all

Comment: Check my answer again, I added some other solutions. Maybe someone will be better for your need.

Comment: Thanks -  I fixed the logic on the original question (needs a setAxes, rather than axis.add() - and the `every` works now giving `Condition not satisfied:

b.getRuns().every(){ it.logFile.text.contains("TEST/1") }
| |         |
| |         false
| [test0 Â» 1 #1, test0 Â» 2 #1, test0 Â» 3 #1]
test0 #1`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
def 'matrix'() {
    given:
        def matrixProject = rule.createMatrixProject()
        def axis = new TextAxis('TEST', "1", "2", "3")
        matrixProject.axes.add(axis)

    expect:
        with( matrixProject.scheduleBuild2(0).get() ) {
            logFile.text.contains("Some String!")
            runs.every { it.logFile.text.contains("Another String") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.xxxxx.with() is applicable for argument types: (hudson.matrix.MatrixBuild, org.jenkinsci.plugins.xxxxxxx$_$spock_feature_0_2_closure3) values: [test0 #1, org.jenkinsci.plugins.xxxx$_$spock_feature_0_2_closure3@1adc811d]
Possible solutions: with(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), find(), wait(long), wait(long, int), Mock()` I tried using `.with{` but that didn't either

Answer (score 1):

Either use `every` instead of `each`, or use a nested `assert`.